# Issue with cloudstorage python library in uploading images ONLY

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage

I have managed to successfully read/write files (xls) to bucket I have created using App Engine App running on GAE. However, when I try to do the same for image files, it is giving error:

'Request to Google Cloud Storage timed out.', DownloadError('Unable to fetch URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/parse_scratch/TTM150 MSM63 04504.jpg',)

Please help.

---

In response to the question by Benson, answer (along with code I have been using) is below:

Individual file sizes:

Less then 400 KB (some are less than 100KB) and one image that I have uploaded to GCS that I'm trying to read out simply by calling gcs.open(fname, 'r') is 22KB. The xls files, however, that I'm trying to read from the same bucket (using same code) is 5 MB !

Code:

What does it do: it opens the zipfile of images stored under static file of my Django Framework, reads files through it one by one, and tries to store data on GCS using gcs_write(). Similar code (without going through zip file, and trying to read a stored image in the GCS is not able to read either, generating the same error above).

```
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(join(IMAGEPATH, f), 'r')

    for imgwpath in zip.namelist():
        if not (('.jpg' in imgwpath) or ('.jpeg' in imgwpath) or ('.gif' in imgwpath)):
            continue

        full_name = imgwpath.split('/')
        image_name = full_name[len(full_name)-1]

        data = zip.read(imgwpath)
        if '.jpg' or '.jpeg' in image_name:
            type = 'jpeg'
        elif '.gif' in image_name:
            type = 'gif'

        filename = BUCKET + image_name
        gcs_file = gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type = 'image/jpeg')
        gcs_file.write(data)
        gcs_file.close()
```

Comment: How large are the image files you're trying to write?

Comment: Which line in your code does the error message refer to?

Comment: use of gcs library, I suppose. As you can see the last three lines are the ONLY one about GCS.

Comment: In the error log, it should tell you exactly which line the error occurred on.  It would be most helpful to have that information.

Comment: /base/data/home/apps/s~parsescratch/2.368182426280182786/cloudstorage/storage_api.py in do_request_async, line 84

Comment: Thanks for sharing that; can you tell me which in the text you pasted maps to line 84?

Comment: The point is that the exception is thrown in line 84 of storage_api.py which is the GCS python library (not my code).

Comment: Alternatively, can you provide me a sample code that manages to read and write image files to GCS using GCS library ? Thx.

Comment: Benson, concretely - it's happening because I'm calling gcs_open()

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm seeing this problem in my application too.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue, so I thought I'd answer this in case someone else experiences this issue.

It appears that it's due to spaces in the filename.

When assigning filename, I replaced spaces with underscores, which seemed to resolve the issue:

```
    filename = BUCKET + image_name
    filename = filename.replace(" ", "_") 
    gcs_file = gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type = 'image/jpeg')
    gcs_file.write(data)
    gcs_file.close()
```